# Python custom datetime(?) format handling

Tags: python, date, datetime, time, strptime

Let's say i have a string representing a time with number of day of the week:

For example '52300', which means 5th day of week(Friday), 23 Hours 00 Minutes.

How do i parse it to time or datetime object to add a timedelta(hours=3) and get it back to this strange format? Expected output is '60200' string.

I have tried:

```
tow_str = '52300'
tow = datetime.datetime.strptime(tow_str, "%w%H%M") + datetime.timedelta(hours=3)
print(tow.strftime("%w%H%M"))
```

which returns '20200' instead of '60200'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Parsing a date with `%w` accurately requires that you include the date itself, otherwise the date is set to 1900-01-01:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> tow_str = '52300'
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(tow_str, "%w%H%M")
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 23, 0)
```

and you always end up with `1` when formatting back to a string:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(tow_str, "%w%H%M").strftime("%w%H%M")
'12300'
```

Without a date, `%w` is meaningless.

You could produce a date from the weekday based on today's date, and only parse the time:

```
def nearest_date_for_weekday(weekday):
    today = datetime.date.today()
    return today + datetime.timedelta(days=weekday - today.weekday())

parsed_date = datetime.datetime.combine(
    nearest_date_for_weekday(int(tow_str[0])), 
    datetime.datetime.strptime(tow_str[1:], '%H%M').time())

print parsed_date.strftime('%w%H%M')
```

So this produces a complete `datetime` object, so formatting back to a string gives a meaningful value for `%w`.