# How to get hhh:mm datetime format with Python?

Tags: python, datetime

Is there any way to get the following datetime format in Python?

```
hhh:mm
```

For example:

```
126:00
```

I'd like to be able to do the following operation:

```
126:00 - 67:56 - 12:00 = 46:04
```

I tried with...

```
hours_d = datetime.datetime.strptime('126:00','%H:%M')
```

...but obviously it returns `hh:mm`.

**SOLVED:**

Thanks to @Bluehorn and @lenz for your help!!!!!

```
    # h1=126:00
    h1_h, h1_m = [int(x) for x in h1.split(":")]
    # h2=67:56
    h2_h, h2_m = [int(x) for x in h2.split(":")]
    # h3=12:00
    h3_h, h3_m = [int(x) for x in h3.split(":")]

    h1_d = timedelta(hours=h1_h)+ timedelta(minutes=h1_m)
    # 5 days, 6:00:00
    h2_d = timedelta(hours=h2_h)+ timedelta(minutes=h2_m)
    # 2 days, 19:56:00
    h3_d = timedelta(hours=h3_h)+ timedelta(minutes=h3_m)
    # 12:00:00

    result = h1_d - h2_d -h3_d
    # 1 day 22:04:00
```

I'll update my answer when I get the result in hh:mm.

Comment: Why do you need this rather uncommon format? If you want to do time difference calculations, just use the datetime.timedelta type.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28963665/

Comment: Because is the format for the hours worked so I need to work with this date format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/648dcafa7e5f/Lib/_strptime.py#l194 this is not supported - as expected.

The documentation described `%H` as *Hour (24-hour clock) as a decimal number [00,23]*, see https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/time.html?highlight=strptime#time.strftime

Therefore it even fails for two-digit hours:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> hours_d = datetime.datetime.strptime('26:00','%H:%M')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
ValueError: time data '26:00' does not match format '%H:%M'
```

You will have to parse the pair of `HOURS:MINUTES` yourself, as in

```
hours, minutes = [int(x) for x in "126:00".split(":")]
```

Comment: you could also write it as: `hours, minutes = map(int, "126:00".split(":"))`

Comment: I avoid using map in Python 2 since I got bitten by map messing with exceptions thrown in `__iter__`: If the iter fails for any reason on the second argument, map will throw `TypeError: argument 2 to map() must support iteration`. This easily shadows AttributeErrors, database errors etc. - not a problem here, but I just don't use map anymore.